# How to create a sub-package and add existing files intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package, project-structure

I have my project structure something like this.

```
|--daos
|  |
|  |--MyDBReader.java
```

But I want to change it into this one.

```
daos
|
|--readers
|  |
|  |--MyDBReader.java
```

Can anyone tell me the preffered way to do that with **intellij** preserving all dependencies and usages?

Comment: I would probably just create a new folder under `daos`, and then cut-and-paste the content into there.  IntelliJ should be able to detect that you are moving the code, and update all references automatically.

Comment: I'm surprised IntelliJ didn't ask you if you wanted to preserve usages.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, actually your answer is correct, if we gonna do that with the project-structure window in intelliJ. Sorry I didn't get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the better answer is:

1. Go to the project-structure sub-window in IntelliJ.
2. Create new package.
3. Just drag and drop the file from the older location to the new location **from the project-structure sub-window**.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways (AFAIK)

***Method One***

1. Right click the class in the project explorer and `Refactor -> Move` or Select the Class in the project explorer press <kbd>F6</kbd>
2. Then select `To Package` enter the new package name and press `Refactor` button.

***Method Two***

Just change the package statement in MyDBReader.java from `package daos;` to `package daos.readers;`, then you will see red line under the package statement, place the cursor on the statement then do <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> then select 'Move package to daos.readers'. **This method only changes the package but does not update the usages**

Comment: I Have updated my answer. dont want to remove the method one so reorder the methods and mentions the usage part.